# How to load ApplicationContext for junit test for testing file uploading to controller post method

Tags: maven, spring-boot, post, junit, applicationcontext

I'm writing a micro service, using spring boot and maven, that allows for the uploading of images for text to be extracted, using tess4j, and sent back to the user. However I'm writing a JUnit test case for the controller and I'm having trouble loading the applicationcontext for a MockMvc to send a MockMultipartFile to the controller that handles the call from the users.

I've tried researching this problem before asking, I known I need to access an application context to run the request to the controller or use a MockMvcBuilders standaloneSetup for accessing the controller however I was unable to get the standaloneSetup working as well.

The current stack trace for the failed to load ApplicationContext is this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multipartResolver' defined in com.imageProcessing.WebConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver]: Factory method 'multipartResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver]: Factory method 'multipartResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
at com.imageProcessing.WebConfig.multipartResolver(WebConfig.java:17)
at com.imageProcessing.WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d72f8dbc.CGLIB$multipartResolver$0(<generated>)
at com.imageProcessing.WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d72f8dbc$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ed0f4e04.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
at com.imageProcessing.WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d72f8dbc.multipartResolver(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 55 more
```

Currently the controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class ImageProcessingController {
    @Value("$spring.application.fileLocation")
    private String tempFileLocation;

    @PostMapping("/imageUpload")
    public TextResponse handleImageFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        TextResponse textExtracted;
        if(file.isEmpty()){
            textExtracted = new TextResponse("File is empty, Please upload file containing data");
        }else {
            String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();
            try{
                File tempFile = File.createTempFile(tempFileLocation,filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".")+1));
                tempFile.deleteOnExit();
                file.transferTo(tempFile);
                textExtracted = new TextResponse(TextExtractor.getText(tempFile));;
                tempFile.delete();
            }catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                textExtracted = new TextResponse("Error processing image");
            }           
        }
        return textExtracted;
    }
}
```

The JUnit code looks like this:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebConfig.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ImageProcessingControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception{
        File image = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:image1.png");
        byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(image);
        MockMultipartFile imageFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", image.getName(), "image/png", data);

        MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/imageUpload").file(imageFile)).andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
}
```

The WebConfig class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "test.controllers" })
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        return multipartResolver;
    }
}
```

I've seen some example online about a application context xml file but I've been unable to see what is in the file. I do have a appplication.properties file that only sets the upload location for the controller.

I'm unsure how to load the application context for the test to work and gain access to the controller. I known the text extraction works based on another test that only access the TextExtractor class.

The file structure for the project looks like this

```
imageProcessing
     src
         main
              java
                  com.imageProcessing
                  com.textExtraction
              resources
                  application.properties
         test
              java
                  com.imageProcessing
                  com.textExtraction
              resources
                  images
```

I'm just trying to get the test running with out any config problems so I can start testing the controller to see if it works or not.